# Counterexample to $\| X - Y \| \le \left\| \begin{pmatrix} X & 0 \\ 0 & Y \end{pmatrix} \right\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

I was reading the book [Matrix Analysis](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387948461) and have encountered with the following exercise in Chapter IX. A Selection of Matrix Inequalities:

> Let $X, Y$ be positive operators. Show that for every unitarily invariant norm 
>   $$
> \| X - Y \| \le \left\| \begin{pmatrix} X & 0 \\ 0 & Y \end{pmatrix} \right\|.
> $$

---

After some time that I spend proving it I started to plug-in different values for $X$ and $Y$ trying to understand the behaviour of the norms of these matrices. So, I picked the operator norm, which is indeed unitarily invariant norm.

Now, take positive $2\times 2$ matrices
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0.5 \end{pmatrix}, \quad Y = \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I calculated and triple double checked that the inequality above is violated with r.h.s. $\approx 1.46$ and l.h.s. $1.5$.

My question is: Can anyone verify whether this "counterexample" is true or not? If not, where is the mistake?

**UPD:** As it was correctly pointed out by @Ted Shifrin the operators should be Hermitian (symmetric) and the counterexample fails. @amsmath gives the proof for operator norm in comments. Any ideas how it can be proved for any unitarily invariant norm?

Comment: I'm getting the same numbers as you.

Comment: What is the definition of a positive operator?

Comment: @TedShifrin https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/positive-operator.

Comment: @Nate thanks for your work!

Comment: The wording of this exercise is strange. There are two norms here, one defined on $M_n$ and the other defined on $M_{2n}$. Without knowing the relationship between the two norms, there is no way to prove the inequality, regardless of the exact definition of a positive operator. E.g. if $\|\cdot\|$ is a unitarily invariant (and submultiplicative) norm, then so is $c\|\cdot\|$ for any $c\ge1$. So, for any $X,Y$, if you scale up the norm on the LHS enough, the inequality will always be violated.

Comment: I’ve specified with which norm I’m calculating exact numbers. $\| \cdot \|$ is operator norm, regardless where it’s defined on. This inequality can moreover be rewritten so that both sides will on $\mathbb{M}_n$ only.

Comment: Just as I suspected: The definition (to which you linked me) requires that the operator be symmetric (hermitian).

Comment: @Ted, I guess that should it, thanks.

Comment: $\left\|\begin{pmatrix}X & 0\\0 & Y\end{pmatrix}\right\| = \max\{\|X\|,\|Y\|\}$. So, $Y = -X\in\Bbb R$ should be sufficient as a counterexample.

Comment: they both should be positive, if $X = -Y$ then it implies $X = Y = 0$, in which case its all good. @amsmath

Comment: @amsmath the question at least did :D "Let $X, Y$ be $\dots$"

Comment: @pointguard0 You got a point here. The question is: What does "positive operator" mean here?

Comment: yep, as Ted pointed out, the author probably means that the operators are symmetric. @amsmath

Comment: @pointguard0 That doesn't answer my question. I asked what "positive" means? If it means "positive definite", there is definitely no counterexample.

Comment: @pointguard0 I was not talking about how you worded *your* question, but how Bhatia worded his (provided that the problem statement was quoted verbatim).

Comment: For the operator norm you have $((X-Y)u,u) = (Xu,u)-(Yu.u)\le(Xu,u)\le\|X\|$ for all vectors $u$ with $\|u\|=1$. Similarly, $((Y-X)u.,u)\le\|Y\|$. Hence, $\|X-Y\| = \sup_{\|u\|=1}|((X-Y)u,u)|\le\max\{\|X\|,\|Y\|\}$.

Comment: @amsmath yes, its positive definite and thank you for your last comment.

Comment: @amsmath i'd be happy to accept your answer if you choose to post one. If not, should I close the question/post my own answer or anything else? thanks

Comment: @pointguard0 But my comment only proves the claim for the operator norm. I don't have any idea to prove it for an arbitrary unitarily invariant norm.

Comment: @amsmath okay, i've edited the question now.